# sonarcloud sonar-project.properties to ignore files containing a camel case regular expression

Tags: python, sonarcloud

I wanted to ignore camel case regular expression code smell from sonar cloud analysis.  I do have sonar-project.properties within my project:

```
sonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io 
sonar.organization=XXXX
sonar.projectKey=YYYYY 
sonar.projectName=YYYYY
sonar.exclusions=**/*.html,**/*.yml,**/*.sh,**/*.yaml,**/*.xml,**/*.py,**/*.md,**/*_test
```

Could anyone please help me on how to add properties to ignore file with camelcase issue? 
Thanks in advance